# How to package IeEmbed.exe and MozEmbed.exe into an executable Jar file

Tags: file, exe, executable-jar, jdic

I use JDIC in my executable Jar file, when it runs, it needs to have IeEmbed.exe and MozEmbed.exe in the same dir as the Jar file, I wonder if there is a way to package all 3 files into a single executable Jar file, so when I distribute the app, there is only one executable Jar file to worry about, besides, there are problems sending and downloading *.exe files, what's the solution ?

For instance, my executable Jar file is called Java_App.jar, how to get <1>IeEmbed.exe <2>MozEmbed.exe and <3>Java_App.jar into a Jar file called : My_App.jar, and when user double clicks on My_App.jar, it will run the Java_App.jar and find the needed IeEmbed.exe and MozEmbed.exe files from inside the My_App.jar package without unpacking and save them into a local dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem packaging them together per se. The jar file is finally a .zip file.

The problem will come when your app try to load it because it won't be able to find the `.exe` in the system path.

The solution is to make an installable file ( which can be a .zip file ) and expand and copy the `.exe` file for you for instance in a "bin" directory